# ASP.Net MVC - Send Javascript Associative array to a controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to pass a javascript associative array to a controller.

I can pass normal arrays into a controller with this:

```
public JsonResult ProductsByFacets(List<string> facets)
```

but this won't work with associative arrays

Comment: I'm guessing you are referring to object literals (JSON). Google found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx . Hope it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check JsonValueProvider in ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures.

[Sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)