# What object type do I need to use in my Action if the ajax POSTS an array?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I've tried the following with the `List<int>` being always null on the Action:

```
$('td').delegate('.roleoption select', 'change', function() {
    var userRoles = new Array();
    $(this).parent().parent().find('select').each(function() {
        userRoles.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(userRoles); // [1, 4, 3]

    var userId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('td').first().text();
    console.log(userId); // [2]

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CambiarRol", "Administracion")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { user: userId, roles: userRoles },
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Worked ok.");
        }
    });
});
```

And my Action:

```
public ActionResult CambiarRol(int user, List<int> roles)
{
    // "user" is received correctly. "roles" is null.
    return Json(new object());
}
```

What datatype does my Action need to have in order to correctly receive the roles variable information?

Also what do I need to return from my Action if I want "result" to have a message or something?

```
    success: function(result) {
        alert("Worked ok.");
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525053/passing-array-from-jquery-to-mvc-net-controller-giving-null-result-on-controller

Comment: Try use $.toJSON(array). More explanation here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308674/asp-net-mvc-send-javascript-associative-array-to-a-controller

Comment: @djserva: It's not working and doesn't solve the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: Relate but doesn't solve my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281288/js-int-array-to-mvc3-controller

Comment: If you converted roles to JSON  in your JavaScript then the type for roles in your action needs to be a string.  If you need to get it back into an object in your action then you would use the JavascriptSerializer.

Comment: @KevinJunghans: I just want to pass a collection if those ints, it doesn't matter if there are strings or ints as long as they are received on the controller end. The problem isn't creating the data to send, it's how to have the controller recognize the data it's receiving and binding it to the method variable.

Comment: I think you missed my point.  JSON is serialized Javascript objects.  Therefore the data format to use to receive JSON is a string.  I was not referring to the types in your collections.  Try posting the change you made that djserva suggested and you said did not work, because it may be that it was not implemented as djserva intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this before making the call to post.

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

I found this by just realizing that the Array you're sending is actually sent with a key = "roles[]", that's why you always get null on the controller side.

If you change the above, the key will be "roles" and you'll get your list of ints.